# SQLite vs remote database?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm currently creating an android app and 1 of the activities has to display a list of cards with info that's being stored in a database.

My question is what kind of database should I be using?

Should I just get all the info out of the remote database when it has to be loaded or should I insert it into an SQLite database and update that one occasionally?

Comment: The answer would be "It depends on what you need".

Comment: The "key" in order to select the kind of database is how often do you update your database data..

Comment: Ah I could've expected that, it should be updated whenever a user adds an activity.

I was currently going for the remote database option but since a lot of tutorials out there are using SQLite database I thought maybe there was something I'm missing

Comment: @BramNouwen Are you going to have a central database no matter what? Would a local database on the user’s device suffice alone? Or must data changes be reported outside the divine?

Comment: If I'd update the local database occasionally it would suffice. The gist is just that users can add activities and it needs to be displayed on everybody's homepage whenever one is added. So It's either a remote database which is 'contacted' every time a user visits the homepage, or a local one that has the remote database's info and updates whenever something has been added, that's why I asked the question. But after thinking about it a little I think the answer to my question is to just make a connection and get the info out of the remote database every time they visit the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can expect and require your users to have a network connection then a remote database would be simpler than storing local data and syncing. Sync can be tricky.

If the use must be able work offline, then you must go with local storage or database.

Use SQLite only if your data needs are indeed "lite". Otherwise consider using a more serious database such as [H2 Database](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android).

Comment: It is expected that they have a network connection, yes. The users need to be able to contact the activity starter and be able to join and stuff. So like I mentioned in another comment I came to realise I do indeed need a remote one and not a local on that syncs. I'll check out the H2 database link you mentioned, thanks!